# AWS S3AsyncClient is giving credential issue while trying to read content from Object Storage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am trying to use AWS S3AsyncClient to get/read file from Object Storage. My ultimate intention is to use this in my Vert.x project but before using with Vert.x I wanted to do get it working standalone. By following multiple forums I have written below code but it is giving error "software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Credentials must not be null.". Even though I am providing credentials here, it says it's not getting them. Can anyone please help me here?

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncResponseTransformer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;

public class S3AsyncStreamOps {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AwsCredentialsProvider creds = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("my_access_key", "my_secret_key"));
    S3AsyncClient s3Client;
    try {
        s3Client = S3AsyncClient.builder().credentialsProvider(creds)
                .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
                .endpointOverride(new URI("https://someobjectstorage.server.com:9021"))
                .build();
        CompletableFuture<GetObjectResponse> futureGet = s3Client.getObject(
                GetObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket("my_bucket_name")
                        .key("/somepath/anotherpath/myData.pdf")
                        .build(),
                AsyncResponseTransformer.toFile(Paths.get("/osfile/myfile.pdf")));
        futureGet.get();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

With above code I am getting exception stack trace as:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Credentials must not be null.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at com.aexp.ecp.vertx.spring.verticles.S3AsyncStreamOps.main(S3AsyncStreamOps.java:54)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Credentials must not be null.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.ThrowableUtils.asSdkException(ThrowableUtils.java:98)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonAsyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonAsyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:263)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:205)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.execute(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:134)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsAsyncClientHandler.execute(AwsAsyncClientHandler.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3AsyncClient.getObject(DefaultS3AsyncClient.java:3949)
    at com.aexp.ecp.vertx.spring.verticles.S3AsyncStreamOps.main(S3AsyncStreamOps.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Credentials must not be null.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Validate.paramNotNull(Validate.java:117)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.Aws4SignerParams.<init>(Aws4SignerParams.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.AwsS3V4SignerParams.<init>(AwsS3V4SignerParams.java:27)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.AwsS3V4SignerParams.<init>(AwsS3V4SignerParams.java:21)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.AwsS3V4SignerParams$BuilderImpl.build(AwsS3V4SignerParams.java:121)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsS3V4Signer.constructAwsS3SignerParams(AwsS3V4Signer.java:93)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsS3V4Signer.sign(AwsS3V4Signer.java:59)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.SigningStage.signRequest(SigningStage.java:63)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.SigningStage.execute(SigningStage.java:49)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.SigningStage.execute(SigningStage.java:35)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:208)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:107)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:102)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage.execute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage.execute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:51)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:29)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(AsyncApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(AsyncApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonAsyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonAsyncHttpClient.java:191)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this finally. It was a dependency issue between aws-sdk-java 2.10.56 and my previous sync aws-java-sdk-bundle 1.11.368. I created a separate project with only aws-sdk-java 2.10.56 and it started working properly. Able to read file from Object Storage and save on local system now.